# Datagridview Time IN/OUT

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

```
int rowCount = dtgManageStudents.RowCount;
if (txtID.Text != "")
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < rowCount; x++)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        string timeIN = time.ToString("hh:mm tt");
        string timeOUT = time.ToString("hh:mm tt");
        string lname = dtgManageStudents.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim(),
            fname = dtgManageStudents.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Trim(),
            mname = dtgManageStudents.Rows[x].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim();
        string studentName = lname + ", " + fname + " " + mname;
        string stu = dtgManageStudents.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim();


        if (txtID.Text == stu)
        {
            int dtrRC = dtr.RowCount;
            if (dtrRC == 0)
            {
                int n = dtr.Rows.Add();
                dtr.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = uid;
                dtr.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = studentName;
                dtr.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = timeIN;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < dtrRC; y++)
                {
                    string dtrUID = dtr.Rows[y].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim();
                    if (txtID.Text == dtrUID && dtr.Rows[y].Cells[3].Value == null)
                    {
                        dtr.Rows[y].Cells[3].Value = timeOUT;
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        int n = dtr.Rows.Add();
                        dtr.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = uid;
                        dtr.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = studentName;
                        dtr.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = timeIN;
                    }

                }
            }
            count = 1;
        }

    }
    if (count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ID Number not found");
        txtID.Text = "";
        count = 0;
        txtID.Focus();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter student ID Number");
    txtID.Focus();
}
```

So I have two(2) datagridviews, (1) records of students (2) an attendance for students.

What I want to happen is that when I input an ID number, it will read the textbox and find it in datagridview1 if there's a matching id number. If there's a match then it will add new row in datagridview2 that containts ID number, Student Name, time IN/OUT.

My problem is that whenever I input for a 3rd row (3rd attendance) it duplicates. For my 3rd input of time IN, there will be 5 rows instead of 3 rows only.

Comment: @HansPassant I considered adding `break;` see this: `else 
                            {
                                int n = dtr.Rows.Add();
                                dtr.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = uid;
                                dtr.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = studentName;
                                dtr.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = timeIN;
    break;
                            }

`

Comment: @HansPassant when I do that, it doesn't insert time in time out. it add new row